# while(br.readLine() != null)|Window application, java

Tags: java, window, bufferedreader, filereader, bufferedwriter

```
try {
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter("D:\\LOL\\" + choice.getSelectedItem() + "\\KDA.txt", true)));
                    FileReader fr = new FileReader("D:\\LOL\\" + choice.getSelectedItem() + "\\KDA.txt");
                    BufferedReader br = new  BufferedReader(fr);

                    String suma ;
                    while(br.readLine() != null){
                        Integer.parseInt(suma);
                        suma = 0; //type mismatch: cannot convert from int to String
                        suma += Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
                        textField_4.setText(suma);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e2) {

                }
```

i know that this loop is bad and just need to make a loop that gonna add all numbers in file and then divide by the number of the numbers. i mean when you have file D:\Lol\Plik\KDA.txt and there is 4,0 2,3 12,7 4,3 (for example) and i need to do a loop : 4,0 +2,3 +12,7+4,3/4 = suma textField_setText(suma);
by using buffered reader

Comment: `suma == null`, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you are searching for but you have no Integer variable for `Integer.parseInt(suma);` and then you set `suma`to zero. Is that what you want? Additional you parse an empty `suma`-String.

Here is based on the comments the code-Snippet:

```
String input = br.readLine();
int sum = 0;
int all = 0;
while(input != null){
  sum += Double.parseDouble(su.replace(",", "."));
  all++;
  input = br.readLine();
}

System.out.println(sum/all);
```

Comment: i know that this loop is bad and just need to make a loop that gonna add all numbers in file and then divide by the number of the numbers.
i mean when you have file  D:\\Lol\\Plik\\KDA.txt and there is
4,0
2,3
12,7
4,3 (for example)
and i need to do a loop :
4,0 +2,3 +12,7+4,3/4 = suma
textField_setText(suma);

Comment: First you have to know if its a line or every value on a different line. If its one line than you only need this one and get the Values with `split(" ")`-function and PArse it with `Double`and not `Integer`. Than you can collect all parsed `Doubles` into an `array` and do a loop to build the sum. After that `sum/array.length()`and you got your League of Legends Kill/Death/Assisst-Values

Comment: every value is on next line.

Comment: sum have no arguments

Comment: i dont understand your comment sry ? What did you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

```
while (br.readLine() != null)
```

Stop right there. This is already invalid. You've just read a line and thrown it away. What you need to write is

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
```

and then process `line` inside the loop.

You're also calling `readLine()` inside the loop, and without checking it for null. It isn't going to give you the same line twice.